# Table Cells with different widths in different rows

Tags: html, css

I am weak in CSS, and I am trying to put a table in my html page, it has two rows and five columns per row(of course it is simplified), and it should look like this (the table is a hand-drawing table, it does not come so precise, I`m sorry for that.):

[image]

But mine looks like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50px" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:50px" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:50px" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:50px" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:25px">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:25px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:50px" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:50px" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:50px" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width:50px" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code in jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LeoZhao/cR2qd/3/).

NOTE:Any styles could be added, but structure of table could not be changed.

My problem is not the border style of table, but the width of cells, it seems that cells has a erratic width, I hope the right-border of first cell in second row could reach to the middle of bottom-border of first cell in first row, and the right-border of first cell in first row could reach to the middle of top-border of second cell in second row, so is others.

I have tried my best, but it still does not work. How could I do to match the requirement? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want like this? http://jsfiddle.net/cR2qd/4/

Comment: What the heck are the colspans for? A colspan is to make one field match the length of x fields in the upper row, are you sure that you understood its proper use?

Comment: @Beginner I`m sorry, I didn`t mention my problem clearly, my problem is not the border style of table, but the width of cells, it seems that cells has a erratic width.

Comment: @Steini I have no idea for match the table that been required, so I tried colspan, it is not necessary.

Comment: -1 for inline CSS styling. Use stylesheets.

Comment: @Jazza -1 on a question means the question is not helpful/clear/no effort. I think you should instead put an answer forward with that suggestion instead.

Comment: @JamesKhoury Using inline styling is not helpful for people reading the question. Especially people learning HTML & CSS.

Comment: @Jazza Its a question. If it wasn't wrong it wouldn't be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `<colgroup>` element to achieve this:

```
<table border="1">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 25px"/>
        <col style="width: 25px"/>
        <col style="width: 25px"/>
        <col style="width: 25px"/>
        <col style="width: 25px"/>
        <col style="width: 25px"/>
        <col style="width: 25px"/>
        <col style="width: 25px"/>
        <col style="width: 25px"/>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It will tell the table that there are 9 columns and each row will span the columns as you originally had.

---

There are other non-table ways to acheive what you are looking for. Here is one quick example:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
div.row
{
    clear:both;
}
div div div
{
    width: 50px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: -1px;
}

div div:nth-child(2n+1) div:first-child,
div div:nth-child(2n) div:last-child
{
    width: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tables within tables..

```
     <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
              <tr>
                 <td style="width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
                 <td style="width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
                 <td style="width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
                 <td style="width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
                 <td style="width:25px">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <table border="1">
            <tr> 
              <td style="width:25px">&nbsp;</td>
              <td style="width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
              <td style="width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
              <td style="width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
              <td style="width:50px">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

This way you will never have that problem...

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need to have at least one row that defines the width of individual cells (ones that are not using `cellspan`s):

http://jsfiddle.net/cR2qd/7/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/cR2qd/7/)

HTML:

```
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
td {
    width: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the two rows I need appear correctly, but how do I deal with the first row in your code? Because I could not let costomers see an empty row at the top, I tried add style 'display:none' to first row, it returns...